# Parallel processing of large xml files in python

Tags: python, xml, parallel-processing

I have several large xml files that I am parsing (extracting some subset of the data and writing to file), but there are lots of files and lots of records per file, so I'm attempting to parallelize.

To start, I have a generator that pulls records from the file (this works fine):

```
def reader(files):
    n=0
    for fname in files:
        chunk = ''
        with gzip.open(fname, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                if '<REC' in line or ('<REC' in chunk and line != '</REC>'):
                    chunk += line
                    continue
                if line == '</REC>':
                    chunk += line
                    n += 1
                    yield chunk
                    chunk = ''
```

A process function (details not relevant here, but also works fine):

```
def process(chunk,fields='all'):
    paper = etree.fromstring(chunk)
    #
    # extract some info from the xml
    #
    return result # result is a string
```

Now of course the naive, non-parallel way to do this would be as simple as:

```
records = reader(files)
with open(output_filepath,'w') as fout:
    for record in records:
        result = process(record)
        fout.write(result+'\n')
```

But now I want to parallelize this. I first considered doing a simple map-based approach, with each process handling one of the files, but the files are of radically different sizes (and some are really big), so this would be a pretty inefficient use of parallelization, I think. This is my current approach:

import multiprocessing as mp

```
def feed(queue, records):
    for rec in records:
        queue.put(rec)
    queue.put(None)

def calc(queueIn, queueOut):
    while True:
        rec = queueIn.get(block=True)
        if rec is None:
            queueOut.put('__DONE__')
            break
        result = process(rec)
        queueOut.put(result)

def write(queue, file_handle):
    records_logged = 0
    while True:
        result = queue.get()
        if result == '__DONE__':
            logger.info("{} --> ALL records logged ({})".format(file_handle.name,records_logged))
            break
        elif result is not None:
            file_handle.write(result+'\n')
            file_handle.flush()
            records_logged +=1
            if records_logged % 1000 == 0:
                logger.info("{} --> {} records complete".format(file_handle.name,records_logged))

nThreads = N

records = reader(filelist)

workerQueue = mp.Queue()
writerQueue = mp.Queue()
feedProc = mp.Process(target = feed , args = (workerQueue, records))
calcProc = [mp.Process(target = calc, args = (workerQueue, writerQueue)) for i in range(nThreads)]
writProc = mp.Process(target = write, args = (writerQueue, handle))

feedProc.start()
for p in calcProc:
    p.start()
writProc.start()

feedProc.join()
for p in calcProc:
    p.join()

writProc.join()

feedProc.terminate()
writProc.terminate()
for p in calcProc:
    p.terminate()

workerQueue.close()
writerQueue.close()
```

Now, this works in the sense that everything gets written to file, but then it just hangs when trying to join the processes at the end, and I'm not sure why. So, my main question is, what am I doing wrong here such that my worker processes aren't correctly terminating, or signaling that they're done?

I think I could solve this problem the "easy" way by adding timeouts to the calls to `join` but this (a) seems like a rather inelegant solution here, as there are clear completion conditions to the task (i.e. once every record in the file has been processed, we're done), and (b) I'm worried that this could introduce some problem (e.g. if I make the timeout too short, couldn't it terminate things before everything has been processed? And of course making it too long is just wasting time...).

I'm also willing to consider a totally different approach to parallelizing this if anyone has ideas (the queue just seemed like a good choice since the files are big and just reading and generating the raw records takes time).

**Bonus question:** I'm aware that this approach in no way guarantees that the output I'm writing to file will be in the same order as the original data. This is not a huge deal (sorting the reduced/processed data won't be too unwieldy), but maintaining order would be nice. So extra gratitude if anyone has a solution that ensure that will preserve the original order.

Comment: Curious how large are the XML files? You say *large*, *really big*, etc. but not once mention file sizes. 50 MB? 250 MB? 1 GB? And mention your CPU capacity (OS, RAM, bit). Also, look into [iterparse](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm) that custom builds trees incrementally for large files. Sorry, not to familiar with parallel processing.

Comment: The compressed file are as large as 1GB, but this is variable. Looking at 50k - 2M XML records per file. I have plenty of resources (60 cores, 2TB RAM), and am just trying to avoid reading everything serially.